# Conversão de tipos em Python

Tags: python, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo, números-binários

Ao escrever alguns exemplos didáticos em Python 2.7, deparei-me com a seguinte situação no programa a seguir:

```
a = 0b101
b = 0b111
c = a+b
print c
```

O resultado desse programa é 12 (decimal). Se eu quiser que seja apresentado um valor binário no resultado da soma, tenho que converter o valor obtido para binário, e então o programa fica assim:

```
a = 0b101
b = 0b111
c = bin(a+b)
print c
```

Ora, sabendo que o Python é fortemente tipado (não aceita conversão automática de tipos), como que, determinando-se valores binários nas variáveis a e b, e somando seus valores, ele me apresenta como valor da soma um valor decimal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque o tipo continua sendo o mesmo. Representação binária e representação decimal são **representações** do mesmo tipo. O valor de representar de uma forma não significa que o valor é outro, menos ainda que o tipo é outro. Não está havendo conversão alguma.

A função [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) não gera um número binário, porque tecnicamente todo número não deixa de ser binário, o que esta função faz é gerar uma **string** com a representação binária do número, assim como se você não usar função alguma o que você verá por padrão é a representação decimal de um número. Mas não se engane também está vendo uma *string* com os algarismos decimais, não está vendo o número em si.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).